# Fonts way to big with Awesome WM

Tags: fonts, awesome

I previously tried to use KDE with Awesome WM, and currently try just to use Awesome WM. I use a Vicious battery widget and `nm-applet` for networking. It works pretty well.

However, all my fonts are way too big. I assume that the ThinkPad X220 screen sets a resolution around 120 DPI which then causes all fonts to become bigger:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2013-12-10/screenshot5.png

With KDE, I had the font resolution forced to 96 DPI, which worked well. When I start the KDE `systemsettings` and go into the fonts menu, change something and back again, some programs, like Dolphin and Firefox, will pick up the right font sizes. However, Konsole does not, and it does not make sense to me. See Konsole and Dolphin next to each other:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2013-12-10/screenshot6.png

Another thing that changed, even when I log in with KDE+Awesome again, is that all fonts appear to be a little thinner. I guess that some anti-alias changed, but I have no idea what that was.

How can I get my fonts to behave normally?

Comment: What is the [correct DPI of your monitor](http://dpi.lv/)?

Comment: It probably is 120, but I want it to be 96. I now call `xrandr --dpi 96` and everything is fine again.

Comment: If you visit the site I linked to, it will tell you what it *actually* is; and then you can configure your system to display at the intended DPI and not have to use the `xrandr` workaround...

Comment: My desktop screen has 94 DPI. The laptop has 130 DPI. But I do want around 96 on both!

Answer (score 2):

Best way to achieve this kind of tuning is using [Xresouces](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources) configuration.

for instance `~/.Xresources` could look as:

```
Xft.dpi: 96.0
```